# Invoke the Powershell Script during local testing with MSBuild

Tags: azure, azure-devops, msbuild, ado, msbuild-task

I am trying to call a powershell script for local testing

```
<Target Name="RunPowerShellScript" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition="'$(LocalBuild)' == 'true'">
<Exec LogStandardErrorAsError="true" WorkingDirectory="$(EnlistmentRoot)" Command="pwsh -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File  &quot;$(EnlistmentRoot)\src\helloworld.ps1&quot;" />
    </Target>
```

The current setup isn’t functioning as expected. If I eliminate $(LocalBuild), it operates correctly. However, it’s also invoked in the ADO pipeline, and I prefer not to have it there.

I’ve set LocalBuild to false in the props file and incorporated a target in the build file under build.target.

```
$(LocalBuild)' == 'true'
```

Comment: When you set the localBuild to false, will the RunPowerShellScript target skip during msbuild process? Do you mean that you need to skip the RunPowerShellScript target when using azure devops pipeline?

Comment: Yeah, I mean, I want to run this script while building the project locally, not in azure devops pipeline. I want to skip there.

Comment: can you check if the msbuild argument: `/p:LocalBuild=false` can help you skip the step in Azure DevOps Pipeline. You can refer to my answer

Answer (score 0):

> I want to run this script while building the project locally, not in azure devops pipeline. I want to skip there.

Based on your requirement, you can add the msbuild argument:  `/p:LocalBuild=false` when using Azure DevOps Pipeline.

For example:

```
steps:
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution'
  inputs:
    msbuildArgs: ' /p:LocalBuild=false'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
```

In this case, you don't need to change the LocalBuild Value in the props file. And the RunPowerShellScript target will skip in Azure DevOps Pipeline.

The msbuild argument will override the value in the props file.

**Update:**

csproj file sample:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <LocalBuild>true</LocalBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>

......

  <Target Name="RunPowerShellScript" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition="'$(LocalBuild)' == 'true'">
    <Exec LogStandardErrorAsError="true" WorkingDirectory="$(EnlistmentRoot)" Command="pwsh -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File  &quot;$(EnlistmentRoot)\src\helloworld.ps1&quot;" />
  </Target>
```

When we run the project on local machine, it will run the PowerShell script.

When we run the project in Azure Pipeline, we can set the  msbuild argument: `/p:LocalBuild=false`. Then the build target will be skipped.

Comment: Is there any way to do it in Directory.build.target file only.

Comment: And one more thing, when I am adding Condition="'$(LocalBuild)' == 'true' it's not working locally also. So, If I remove this condition it will work in local build as well as devops, but my requirement is to run locally

Comment: Can you share how you define the  LocalBuild in your props  file? I tried to define it in  .csproj file and it can work as expected

Comment: <LocalBuild>false</LocalBuild>

Comment: Are you suggesting that the localBuild should be difined in .csproj file.

Comment: when you set the LocalBuild  to true, will it run the powershell script on your local machine

Comment: It's not running when I am setting it true. That's the problem

Comment: When I set the variable and the build target at csproj file, it can work as expected.

Comment: Can you share the snapshot how you are declaring in csproj file.

Comment: @Sweta Refer to my update in the  answer and check if it can work for you.